# Basic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider these $3$ sets:
$X = \{1,2,3\}$
$Y = \{\{1,2,3\}\}$
$Z = \{\{\{1,2,3\}\}\}$

Is it fair to say:
$X$ is an element of $Y$
$Y$ is an element of $Z$
$X$ is NOT an element of $Z$?

Comment: Yes you may. "A box that contains a hat and nothing else is not the same thing as a hat" (P.R. Halmos, Naive set theory, p.4)

Comment: Also, none of these are subsets of any of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. $X$ is not an element of $Z$, because $Z$ contains only one element, and that element is $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$

The only way for $X$ to be an element of $Z$ would be if $X=\{\{1,2,3\}\}$, but since $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ contains **one** element and $X$ contains **three** elements (assuming that $1\neq 2$ and $2\neq 3$ and $1\neq 3$), this is not true.

Comment: I think this is the first answer on this site I've read that includes "assuming $1\ne2$ etc." in it.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Just to make sure nobody warns me I forgot the assumption :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct. $X\in Y$ and $Y\in Z$, but $X\notin Z$.

Unless of course you happen to interpret $1=2=3=\{1\}$, in which case $X=\{X\}=Y=\{Y\}=Z$ and then $X\in Z$. But that is not a standard interpretation.

Comment: "not standard" is quite mild :)

Comment: Hagen, I'm sure there are some crackpots and cranks out there who would stipulate that. (Although they will probably disagree that $X\in Z$ too) :-P

Comment: $1=\{1\}$ makes me feel slightly uneasy. As does $1=2$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: If we believe certain people, then ZFC proves these equalities. It's a good thing we don't have to believe them, right? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've once seen someone who claimed that Cantor's diagonal argument didn't work, because if the original list is $(0,0.1,0.11,0.111,\dots)$, and you diagonalize to get a new number, you can only ever get something like $0.11\dots11$, _no matter how many digits you diagonalize!_, which is already in the list. So you don't get a new number. I think this was on the arXiv, but I can only hope I'm misremembering.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Not quite what you described, but... http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305310.pdf

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, that's a different paper. (For those who don't want to read: The number $11\!\dots\!112$, defined as the limit of the infinite sequence $2,12,112,1112,\dots$, must be finite, because all of the numbers in the sequence are finite. Right? In any case, Cantor's diagonal argument can be applied to $\Bbb N$, so there's no bijection from $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$. Which means $\Bbb N$ doesn't exist, and neither do any infinite cardinals.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw You are completely missing the difference between *potential* and *actual* infinity. Allow such philosophical hogwash into mathematics, and you can prove anything!